# Adding a "C" wire for a wireless theromstat

Tags: hvac

I have a heat only system with two wires leading to the thermostat - red and white - and am wanting to add a wireless thermostat.  The new thermostat however requires a "C" wire.  Can I add a C wire?

Comment: Browse [tag:thermostat-c-wire] to see several variations of answers to how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can definitely add a `C` wire.  How you do it, and how difficult it is completely depends on your equipment.